# Troubles with external configuration

Tags: drush, configuration, installation-profiles

I'm working in the creation of a custom profile.

When the installation is already finished, on the configuration module [/admin/config/development/configuration](http://#) appears the following warning

> The staged configuration cannot be imported, because it originates
>   from a different site than this site. You can only synchronize
>   configuration between cloned instances of this site.

All my configuration based on new changes is exported to

> web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install

using the following sh file

```
ddev exec drush cex
find ./web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install/ -type f -exec sed -i -e '/^uuid: /d' {} \;
find ./web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install/ -type f  -exec sed -i -e '/_core:/,+1d' {} \;

rm -f ./web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install/core.extension.yml ./web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install/update.settings.yml ./web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install/file.settings.yml
```

so, what i'm doing wrong or what else is missing?

Comment: Did you strip the UUIDs and config hashes from the config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about a relative path in the file:

> web/sites/default/settings.php

```
$config_directories['sync'] = 'web/profiles/DISTRIBUTION_NAME/config/install';
```